# Render a view in slim does'nt show the view with its css and bootstrap

Tags: php, css, slim

I'm new in slim framework and in PHP 5,
I've copied a template folder download from the internet on my folder `'/Template'` which is the `'template.path'` and I've renamed the folder download `'/Default'` .
When I want to render the view to a page from 'Default' folder I've written:

```
 $app->get('/auth', function() use ($app) {
        $app->render('/Default/pages/examples/lockscreen.html');
    });
```

When I go to http://localhost/Site/index.php/auth, it shows me the content without its CSS and its Bootstrap.

And in lockscreen.html, the link to the CSS and the bootstrap file are written like that:

```
<link href="../../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this is the architecture of the folder /Default :

- /Template

  - /Default

    - /bootstrap
    - /build
    - /dist
    - /pages

      - /examples

        - lockscreen.html

Comment: Are you using a template engine?

Comment: Can you provide the full structure of the site? (Or at least relation of above structure to index.php?)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a correct answer without knowing your site's complete directory structure, but the reason your template file is not pulling in the .css files is because the generated page is (normally) relative to your site's public (web) root, not to the template file. So, for example, if your web root is /Default, the css includes in the template should be:

```
<link href="/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It would help to know where your index.php file is located within the directory structure - it should be located in your site's public root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it!
It's about the root to the css file and the bootstrap file and this is what i've done :

```
<link href="./Template/Default/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./Template/Default/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: You should accept the answer that solves your question by clicking the check below up and down votes.